# How to use the COUNT function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to set up the best basketball team for fantasy basketball in the 2020-2021 season. I created a database for basketball player's stats and imported a table that contains projections and draft rankings for this coming season. I'm focusing on players who play in the center position, I have used the IFF function to see if they meet a higher stat in a specific category (column). Then what I would like to do is COUNT the number of 'YES' in each row. I want to create another column that adds the values  that contains 'YES' from each row. Would like to know how to make this possible.

```
SELECT [Player]
     , [Position]
     , [Team]
     , IIF (  [MIN]  > 20.83 , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'MIN'
     , IIF (  [GP]   > 70.7  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'GP' 
     , IIF (  [FG%]  > 0.51  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'FG%'
     , IIF (  [REB]  > 6.5   , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'REB' 
     , IIF (  [BLK]  > 0.91  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'BLK' 
     , IIF (  [STL]  > 0.52  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'STL' 
     , IIF (  [TO]   < 1.34  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'TO'
     , 
FROM [ProFantasy].[Basketball]
WHERE [Position] LIKE '%C%';
```

[image]

Comment: COUNT is for counting rows, not values in columns. You can probably make a column out of a chain of IFs by checking each column by name, and if there's a YES, add 1.

Comment: So what does that look like exactly, when you say to make a column out of a chain of IFs ?

Comment: Could you please post the code you used to create the table? The same that is in the screenshot. It is just easier to work on a code that is in plain text than on a picture of a code.

Comment: 1) You click on edit your question; 2) You break a new line, add three backticks ```  3)  On a new line, paste your code; 4) On a new line close the code block with three backticks again

Comment: Ya... I don't have backticks.

Comment: Then [edit] your question, paste the code, select it and click on the `{}` in the editor toolbar. You can also click on the `?` in the upper right corner when editing to get help about how to format your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you could try adding them manually along with the if statements.

```
SELECT [Player]
     , [Position]
     , [Team]
     , IIF (  [MIN]  > 20.83 , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'MIN'
     , IIF (  [GP]   > 70.7  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'GP' 
     , IIF (  [FG%]  > 0.51  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'FG%'
     , IIF (  [REB]  > 6.5   , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'REB' 
     , IIF (  [BLK]  > 0.91  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'BLK' 
     , IIF (  [STL]  > 0.52  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'STL' 
     , IIF (  [TO]   < 1.34  , 'YES' , 'NO' ) AS 'TO'
     , IIF (  [MIN]  > 20.83 , 1 , 0 ) +
       IIF (  [GP]   > 70.7  , 1 , 0 ) +
       IIF (  [FG%]  > 0.51  , 1 , 0 ) +
       IIF (  [REB]  > 6.5   , 1 , 0 ) +
       IIF (  [BLK]  > 0.91  , 1 , 0 ) +
       IIF (  [STL]  > 0.52  , 1 , 0 ) +
       IIF (  [TO]   < 1.34  , 1 , 0 ) AS 'Yes Counts'
FROM [ProFantasy].[Basketball]
WHERE [Position] LIKE '%C%';
```

Comment: IMHO you should learn that it is easier to make calculations from numbers than from strings. "YES" and "NO" are equivalent to 1 and 0. Count the number of YES is the same of the sum of 1s.

Comment: You can learn that (as mentioned before) the COUNT operation works on rows not columns. If one really wanted to use the COUNT, one could look into [transposing](https://www.sqlshack.com/multiple-options-to-transposing-rows-into-columns/) the table, turning rows into columns, then using count. Although that seems a bit too extreme for this problem.

Comment: What's IMHO mean or stand for, also can you show an example of how to use a COUNT function?